# How to modify the object of a javafx object property calling change listeners?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a `javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty<Calendar>`. How can I modify the Calendar, so that javafx is registering it and the change listeners are invoked?

So, when I try to set the calendar field `Calendar.YEAR` is there a better solution than

```
Calendar c = duedateCalendar.get();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR,2017);
duedateCalendar.set(c);
```

Comment: What is wrong with the method you have demonstrated?  Also - what is your use case? `LocalDate` may be more suitable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting a property value will be a no-op if the value you pass is equal to the current value, which in this case it clearly is:

```
Calendar c = duedateCalendar.get();
// c is now a copy of the reference held internally by duedateCalendar

c.set(Calendar.YEAR,2017);
// this updates the Calendar object referenced both by c and internally
// by duedateCalendar. Since the YEAR field in Calendar is just a primitive,
// and is not an observable value in the JavaFX sense, nothing is notified
// of the change

duedateCalendar.set(c);
// the value passed to set here is equal (indeed identical) to the value
// held internally by duedateCalendar (since it's an actual copy of the
// same reference). Internally, duedateCalendar will compare the parameter
// to the value it already holds, will see that they are the same, and
// so will take no action (including not notifying listeners)
```

Consequently no change events will be fired (nothing observable has actually changed).

You can create a new `Calendar` representing the new date and set it to that:

```
Calendar c = duedateCalendar.get();
Calendar newDueDate = Calendar.getInstance();
newDueDate.setTime(c.getTime());
newDueDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
duedateCalendar.set(newDueDate);
```

As an aside, I strongly recommend using the [`java.time` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (e.g. `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`) instead of the legacy `Calendar` class. Classes in this API are largely immutable (so they work better with the JavaFX property classes), and have functional methods that return new instances of the appropriate classes. For example, `LocalDate` is immutable and has methods such as [`LocalDate.plusYears(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plusYears-long-) that return a reference to a new `LocalDate` object. So you can do:

```
// just create a random date sometime in 2016:
Random rng = new Random();
LocalDate random2016Date = LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 1).plusDays(rng.nextInt(365));

// general listener for logging:
ChangeListener<Object> listener = (obs, oldVal, newVal) -> System.out.println(oldVal + " -> " + newVal);


ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(random2016Date);
date.addListener(listener);

// add one year to the current date:
date.set(date.get().plusYears(1));
```